# How to Create a Custom Laravel Rule for Greater Values than the another Parameter

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, rule

How can i rewrite the Rule in Laravel to check

**Here is my Rule**

```
public static $rules = array(
        'StartTime' => 'required',
        'EndTime' => 'required');
```

How can i check for `EndTime` should be more than `StartTime`

**I Tried**

```
'EndTime' => 'required|min:StartTime',
'EndTime' => 'required|digits_between:0,StartTime',
```

But Both are not the Correct one i Guess,,

**So How can i Rewrite to achieve my Goal**

Comment: I fear you have to create your own custom rules, both min and digits_between require integers, not calculated-at-runtime values

Comment: I will be having values like 01.00 or 23.00 like that.. It won't be ?

Comment: the rules are not transformed at runtime to a value, so your rules can never work.

Comment: I ask because it checks for `digits_between:0,StartTime` and shows **The end time must be between 0 and StartTime digits**

Comment: Can you help me in creating custom rules, though i saw this http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules I am passing the validator to model like this **$validation = Validator::make($TimingData, TimingModel::$rules);** And i don't know how to call the custom rule in single statement

Answer (score 2):

I suggest another kind of solution for this question,I think it's not necessary to create custom rules for that.You can do this:

```
$myRule = 'required|min:'.Input::get('StartTime');
```

I should say I considered your **StartTime** value is integer.

Comment: This may not be the most creative method, but for the beginners, this is probably the easiest method to implement.

Comment: @JustinKyleParton You're right,I personally prefer to create custom rules for tougher situations